# Почему получается segmentation fault у программы на yacc?

Tags: c, flexbox, lex, yacc, bison

Я пытаюсь запустить пример(4.3. Обрабатываем конфигурационный файл) из этого [HOW-TO](http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/algol/lex-yacc-howto.html).
Это код, который подан вход как язык L1:

```
zone "." {
        type hint;
        file "/etc/bind/db.root";
};
```

Это исходники, с которыми я работаю:

```
LEX-файл (example6.l)
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%

zone            return ZONETOK;
file            return FILETOK;
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*    yylval=strdup(yytext); return WORD;
[a-zA-Z0-9\/.-]+        yylval=strdup(yytext); return FILENAME;
\"                      return QUOTE;
\{                      return OBRACE;
\}                      return EBRACE;
;                       return SEMICOLON;
\n                      /* ignore EOL */;
[ \t]+                  /* ignore whitespace */;
%%
```

Ниже - файл (example6.y) с грамматикой (yacc)

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define YYSTYPE char *

int yydebug=0;//пока без дебага

void yyerror(const char *str)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"error: %s\n",str);
}

int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}

main()
{
    yyparse();
}

%}

%token WORD FILENAME QUOTE OBRACE EBRACE SEMICOLON ZONETOK FILETOK

%%

commands:
    |    
    commands command SEMICOLON
    ;


command:
    zone_set 
    ;

zone_set:
    ZONETOK quotedname zonecontent
    {
        printf("Complete zone for '%s' found\n",$2);
    }
    ;

zonecontent:
    OBRACE zonestatements EBRACE 

quotedname:
    QUOTE FILENAME QUOTE
    {
        $$=$2;
    }
    ;

zonestatements:
    |
    zonestatements zonestatement SEMICOLON
    ;

zonestatement:
    statements
    |
    FILETOK quotedname 
    {
        printf("A zonefile name '%s' was encountered\n", $2);
    }
    ;

block: 
    OBRACE zonestatements EBRACE SEMICOLON
    ;

statements:
    | statements statement
    ;

statement: WORD | block | quotedname
```

Я компилирую вышеуказанные файлы:

```
yacc -d example6.y
lex (example6.l)
cc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o example6
```

И ловлю Segmentation fault

```
elvin@ubuntu:~/Documents/myfirstlex/conf_file$ ./example6
zone "." {
        type hint;
        file "/etc/bind/db.root";
};Segmentation fault (core dumped)
elvin@ubuntu:~/Documents/myfirstlex/conf_file$
```

Пытаясь разобраться с ошибкой, я запускался в режиме отладки

```
elvin@ubuntu:~/Documents/myfirstlex/conf_file$ ./example6
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reducing stack by rule 1 (line 30):
-> $$ = nterm commands ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 1
Reading a token: zone "." {
        type hint;
        file "/etc/bind/db.root";
        type hint;
};Next token is token ZONETOK ()
Shifting token ZONETOK ()
.............................
Stack now 0 1 3 7 10 13 15
Entering state 18
Reducing stack by rule 10 (line 65):
$1 = token FILETOK ()
$2 = nterm quotedname ()
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Можете объяснить, в чём может быть проблема? Если проблема с strdup, то как это можно избежать её использование?

Comment: Судя по [перому попавшемуся примеру](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/tools/Yacc_lexanal_lex-yyval.html) проблема не в `strdup()`. Код в этом примере как раз соответствует возможному коду strdup-а / Возможно надо попробовать написать присваивание как в нем -- `{ yylval.text = strdup(yytext); return FILENAME; }`

Comment: @avp, они используют union, в моем примере union они ещё не используют

Comment: Да, чудес не бывает. Похоже вам надо досконально разобраться чем на самом деле у вас является  [YYSTYPE](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Lex-YACC-HOWTO-6.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно добавить `#define YYSTYPE char *` перед `#include "y.tab.h"` в LEX-файл.

---

Ошибка банальная и компилятор об этом должен был явно предупреждать:

```
example6.l: В функции «yylex»:
example6.l:12:7: предупреждение: assignment to «YYSTYPE» {aka «int»} from «char *» makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   12 | [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*    yylval=strdup(yytext); return WORD;
      |       ^
example6.l:13:7: предупреждение: assignment to «YYSTYPE» {aka «int»} from «char *» makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   13 | [a-zA-Z0-9\/.-]+        yylval=strdup(yytext); return FILENAME;
```

`HOWTO`'шка писалась в те ламповые времена, когда указатели вмещались в `int` и поэтому на этом особо не заостряли внимания. Сегодня же попытка передать в 32-х битном `int` 64-х битный `char *`, само собой, заканчивается UB и крахом...

Comment: сработало, теперь буду следить за ворнингами.Но как ты догадался, что исправить нужно именно добавлением `#define YYSTYPE char *` и именно  в LEX-файл (ведь тот же `#define YYSTYPE char *` уже есть в example6.y изначально ).Как ты понял,что дело именно в указателе? Можешь так же подсказать, эти [мануалы](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/) в сочетании (LEX+YACC или FLEX+BISON) чем-нибудь отличаются друг от друга или можно читать любую пару из них?

Comment: @Elvin, во-первых, одна из сразу возникших мыслей была, что что-то не так с передачей значения между кодом сгенерированным `lex`'ом и `yacc`'ом… потом немного поигрался с отладчиком — на скорую руку ничего не нашёл… просмотрел ещё раз статью по диагонали — тоже ни за что глаз не зацепился… проверил синтаксис на глупые ошибки — тоже ничего... Потом собственно глаз упал на это пресловутое предупреждение и всё сложилось: и одно из изначальных предположений, и то что в статье в следующей главе предлагается добавить этот `#define` для плюсов, и то что об этом прямым текстом написано… как-то так…

Comment: @Elvin, по статьям не подскажу — lex/yacc я так и не освоил, так что советовать здесь ничего не могу...